# Active Directory Import "No containers to display"

Tags: 2013, active-directory, user-profile-service

I am trying to configure Active Directory Import in SP2013, the problem is that on Add new synchronization connection screen I am getting "**No containers to display**" error after clicking "Populate containers".

[image]

The account which I specified has *replicate directory changes* permissions. The structure looks like this:

[image]

Comment: refer the link : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12545.sharepoint-2013-setting-up-user-profile-synchronization-12.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the connection setting, you should use the **Fully Qualified Domain Name**, and not only the domain name you're using when you're signing in to a computer in the domain. Neither should you use the forest name which looks like tmpl-dev.local in your case. Your FQDN might be **tmpl-dev.company.com** which differs from the forest name and the `<domain name>\<user name>`.

Reference: [First Look: SharePoint Server 2013 Active Directory Import (harbar.net)](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2012/07/23/sp13adi.aspx)

If you have the FQDN in the connection setting input box, then you need to specify *Synchronization Options* in the *Configure Synchronization Settings* page. Select **Use SharePoint Active Directory Import** and save.

[image]

Reference: [Step by Step: Active Directory Import for SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a forward looking zone for your domain to your DC then you can just enter the domain name. I encountered the error "No containers to display" because I used the FQDN. When I changed this to just the domain name it was fine.